# How to send form value to backend in ReactJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, state

I want to send form value which are in a state. Now I want to send this state to backend folder called "controller". How can I do this?

Comment: Here's an answer of mine to a similar question [Sending query string parameters to php via fetch not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63708531/2430549), cheers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send form data from React to express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115640/how-to-send-form-data-from-react-to-express)

Comment: This is one of the doubts that every beginner would ask.First of all, learn about APIs through a tutorial or just attend a class to learn the basics and then proceed. Because if you try to explore everything without learning that will be a complete mess.